# window location with the same page(div id)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

How to make window.location go to the same page but with another different div tag(or through div id like this: href="#id").

```
    if((mins == 0) && (secs == 0)) {
        window.alert("Time is up.Your score is "+score); // change timeout message as required
        window.location = "index.html" // redirects to specified page once timer ends and ok button is pressed
    } else {
        cd = setTimeout("redo()",1000);
    }
```

any help would be appreciated.
thanks in advance.

Comment: You're looking for `location.hash`.

Comment: `window.location = "/absolute/path/to/page#your-div-id";`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.scrollIntoView()` on the targeted element.

```
document.getElementById("the_div_id").scrollIntoView(true);
```

- [MDN `scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.scrollIntoView)

Answer (score -1):

Just add the hash as a string:

```
window.location + '#id';
```